# Positioning parameters in Python script tool dialog box?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, parameters

Is there a way to get the boolean parameters below to be next to each other instead of one on top of the other?

[image]

Comment: It's a good question, but I think the answer is no :( It's worth suggesting to Esri on their [ArcGIS Ideas site](http://ideas.arcgis.com/)...

Comment: Maybe by messing with the tool's stylesheet, but I've never tried: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Changing_tool_dialog_appearance

Comment: @blah238 I always wondered what that was for and have never looked into it. I'll take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @nmpeterson, my understanding is that this is not possible to do, and it is probably not worth experimenting with the tool's stylesheet according to a comment by @[KHibma](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1419/khibma?tab=profile) who is part of Esri's Geoprocessing Team.

Assuming that you are still stuck I recommend (like @nmpeterson) that you submit an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com) - it is one for which I guarantee my vote.

Comment: Style sheet can't position elements like that

Comment: @KHibma I updated my answer as per your comment