# Making vertical spacing between parameters smaller on ArcGIS Script tool dialog

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, parameters

I would like to make space between parameters smaller in ArcGis Script tool. For example, in the image attached I would like to make the distance between two parameter Standard terrain and User defined smaller. These parameters are Boolean data type.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that this may be a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/92551/115 - the only thing to look at is a stylesheet but that may or may not help.

Comment: @PolyGeo: Thank for your suggestions. I will work around with a stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Your question reminds me of [Positioning parameters in Python script tool dialog box?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92551/positioning-parameters-in-python-script-tool-dialog-box) and, although I have not tested it, you may want to look into trying to use a stylesheet.

Such techniques are further described in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226569/controlling-categories-in-script-validation-tools-expanding-groups-by-default/226749#226749) to [Controlling Categories in Script Validation Tools - Expanding Groups By Default](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226569/controlling-categories-in-script-validation-tools-expanding-groups-by-default).